# HTTPステータスコードを100で割って2と比較する意味

Tags: http, d

とあるOSSで以下のようにHTTPステータスコードを検証していました。

```d
private void checkHttpCode() {
  if (http.statusLine.Code / 100 != 2) {
    throw new Exception(http.statusLine.code, http.statusLine.reason);
  }
}
```

このような条件式で検証する理由・メリットがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: ２００番台は成功だからかな。。

Comment: BLUEPIXYさんの言う通りでしょうね。成功以外のステータスが返ってきた時には、その詳細を表示するというコードだと思います。別に、検証をしている訳ではないと思いますが。

Comment: 標準ライブラリでも同様の方法でチェックしてるコードがあるようですね。 [/std/net/curl.d#L1014-L1016](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/v2.071.1/std/net/curl.d#L1014-L1016)

Answer (score 1):

HTTPによるリクエストが受け取られた場合、200番台のステータスコードが返されます。
良く知られている OKを表す200の他に、201～208と226といったものがあります。

[HTTPステータスコード(Wikipedia)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)

D言語では、C言語と同様に　整数を整数で割ると整数になります。
つまり、　200/100 は 2、201/100 も2、(途中は省略)　208/100 も 2、226/100 も2　となる訳です。

そこで、

```
private void checkHttpCode() {
  if (http.statusLine.Code != 200 && http.statusLine.Code != 201 && http.statusLine.Code != 202 && http.statusLine.Code != 203 && http.statusLine.Code != 204 && http.statusLine.Code != 205 && http.statusLine.Code != 206 && http.statusLine.Code != 207 && http.statusLine.Code != 208 && http.statusLine.Code != 226) {
    throw new Exception(http.statusLine.code, http.statusLine.reason);
  }
}
```

という長ったらしいコードが、整数と整数の割り算について知っていると質問のコードのように簡潔に書くことが出来ます。

質問のコードは、上記のコードと比べて、「短くて」「判りやすい」というメリットがあります。

200番台ではないステータスコードが返ってきたという事は、リクエストが受け取られなかった（何らかの不具合が生じた）訳です。
そうした場合に例外処理をする(例外をthrowして、例外処理に移行する）のは、きわめて常識的なコードです。